# Why are Cosmos upserts double the cost of an insert?

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I've created a brand new collection and applied an opt-out indexing policy.

```
{
    "indexingMode": "consistent",
    "automatic": true,
    "includedPaths": [
        {
            "path": "/path/to/included/property/?"
        },
        {
            "path": "/path/to/root/of/multiple/included/properties/*"
        }
    ],
    "excludedPaths": [
        {
            "path": "/*"
        },
        {
            "path": "/\"_etag\"/?"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've then written a basic document to it twice (using `container.UpsertItemAsync()`).

```
Inserting document: {"id":"foo","PartitionKey":"bar"}
RequestCharge = 5.52
Updating document: {"id":"foo","PartitionKey":"bar"}
RequestCharge = 10.29
```

Why is the second write costing me nearly double the RUs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RUs in Azure CosmosDB is calculateed as a factor of `Memory+CPU+IOPS` used to perform an operation. 
While updating a document, It need to first fetch the document then update and insert it back in the collection. Hence, the higher cost of updating a document.